# php - Conflicting view helper names in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, view-helpers, zend-framework3

I am using a `module` called `Facebook` which has a view helper called `shareUrl`. This view helper gets the Facebook share URL for any URL.

However, I have recently added another `module` called `Twitter` which also has a view helper called `shareUrl`.

In Zend Framework version 2 or 3, within views, how can I call one `shareUrl` view helper versus the other?

Just to clarify, the code in my view looks like the following:

```
$facebookShareUrl = $this->shareUrl('https://www.example.com/');
$twitterShareUrl  = $this->shareUrl('https://www.example.com/');
```

I would like `$facebookShareUrl` and `$twitterShareUrl` to store the return values of two different view helpers.

Comment: How did you register these helpers (in module config files)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've got two helpers with the same name, only one is available as it is registered under the given name within the servicemanager (viewhelpermanager). If you switch them around with loading the modules in your `application.config.php` you can change the default. But that is not a real solution to your problem.

So there are multiple ways to get the right viewhelper you need.

1) The best way is to setup an alias for the registered viewhelpers using their FQCN. See some example code where we create aliases that can be used in the viewherlpers like `$this->facebookShareUrl('exmaple.com')`

```
return [
    'view_helpers' => [
       'aliases' => [
           'facebookShareUrl' => FacebookModule\Helper\ShareUrlHelper::class,
           'twitterShareUrl'  => TwitterModule\Helper\ShareUrlHelper::class,
       ],
    ]
]
```

2) Get the helper by its FQCN using the viewhelpermanager in the view itself, using the `PhpRenderer` instance. Within a `view.phtml` file

```
$viewHelperManager = $this->getHelperPluginManager();
$facebookShareUrlHelper = $viewHelperManager->get(FacebookModule\Helper\ShareUrl::class);
$twitterShareUrlHelper = $viewHelperManager->get(TwitterModule\Helper\ShareUrl::class);
```

Comment: I tried method 1 but get error message `A plugin by the name "facebookShareUrl" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager`. Are there any additional steps I need to take to make this method work?

Comment: You need to find out how they registered the viewhelper within their module. I've had no clue as to which package/library you were using so I tried to give a generic solution, which you had to tweak to your situation. If you could link the repo's to the packages on github/packagist I might be able to tweak the example for you.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your reply, I was able to update the modules. The solution for me was to add both 'aliases' and 'factories' sections under 'view_helpers' in the modules being called. I'm not sure if this would have worked if the modules only contained the 'factories' section, but fortunately I own these modules so I was able to update them.